# MongoDB: Updating a document in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents of this schema:

```
{
    _id: something,
    recipients: [{id:1, name:"Andrey", isread:false}, {id:2, name:"John", isread:false}]
}
```

Now, I want to update "isread" for John (id = 2) using `findAndModify()`, because I also need to get the original document.

I'm trying this command:

```
db.messages.findAndModify({query:{'recipients.id':2}, update:{'recipients.$.isread':true}})
```

but what it does, it just replaces the whole "recipients" field with 'recipients.$.isread', so the document now looks like:

```
{
    _id: someid,
    'recipients.$.isread':true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, but it may have been voted down because the documentation states that the value to the update key is a modifier object, which kind of implies the inclusion of the modification instructional key word ($set, $push, etc). I thought your question was a fair once, since I personally find some inconsistencies in the mongodocs use of terminology, particularly with how it refers to various parameter components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use $set like this:

```
db.messages.findAndModify({query:{'recipients.id':2}, update:{$set:{'recipients.$.isread':true}}})
```

Comment: Was this helpful? or still an issue?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. It looks reasonable, I'll mark it as answer when I try it tomorrow. Thanks!