# MongoDB: Updating document in array with dictionary

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I found a [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460394/mongodb-updating-a-document-in-an-array) that comes very close to answering my question, but not quite there.

Take this original question (modifying a document that is in an array) but assume that you do not have a specific change you wish to make. Instead, I have a dictionary of changes that I wish to make. Here is an example:

**Original Document**

```
{
    _id: something,
    recipients: [{id:1, name:"Andrey", isread:false}, {id:2, name:"John", isread:false}]
}
```

**Changes to be made**

```
{
    isread: true,
    fullname: 'jonathan'
}
```

How can I apply this dictionary of changes to John (id:2)?
Incase it is relevant, I am using the [MongoDB-Node.JS Driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify)
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in the question you referenced, you need to use the `$` [positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator), but with `update` in this case:

```
collection.update({_id:something, 'recipients.id': 2}, {$set: {'recipients.$': {
    isread: true,
    fullname: 'jonathan'
}}}, function (err) {...
```

**EDIT**

To not replace the whole array element object you'd have to do something like this:

```
collection.update({_id:something, 'recipients.id': 2}, {$set: {
    'recipients.$.isread': true,
    'recipients.$.fullname': 'jonathan'
}}, function (err) {...
```

Comment: It nearly is working however the whole document is being replaced. Here is an example that is more specific to what I am trying to do: https://gist.github.com/3298315

Comment: I submitted an edit, but it's waiting on peer review. You can use the positional operator multiple times, so instead of setting the entire embedded document at that position, you can set the `"recipients.$.isread"` and `"recipients.$.fullName"` fields individually.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to submit an update for each field in the dictionary? I do not know what fields are going to be updated ahead of time unfortunately, that is why I am trying to just use a dictionary of changes.

Comment: @tgrosinger You can build up your `$set` object dynamically based on what you're calling a dictionary of changes.

Comment: Ah perfect. I will just go through the dictionary and update the keys that are given to me and prepend the "recipients.$.". Thank you