# MongoDB: Updating a dictionary in array in document

Tags: python, mongodb

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871238/mongodb-updating-document-in-array-with-dictionary) which is technically the same but doesn't answer my question fully and was asked 7 years ago.

The problem which I can't solve is updating a dictionary in array in document. I needed to change `deck` to `True`, but it doesn't update it. Also I didn't get any errors.

**Document Structure**

```py
{
            "user": 1234,

            "money": 0
            "inv_max": 100,
            "cards": [
                {
                    "name": "somename",
                    "power": 11,
                    "health": 10,
                    "rarity": 'bronze'
                    "deck": False,
                }
            ],

            "packs": {
                "bronze": 0,
                "silver": 0,
                "gold": 0,
                "diamond": 0,
                "mythical": 0
            }
}
```

**Code which should update it (which I used)**

```py
await db.inventory.update_one(
        {"user": self.user_id},

        {"$set": {f"cards.{index}.deck": True}}
     )
```

In case it's needed, I use MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the positional operator $ to update:

```
db.inventory.updateOne(
   { "user": "1234", "cards.name": "somename"},
   { "$set": { "cards.$.deck" : "True" }} )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index you can do something like this

```
db.inventory.update_one(
        {"user": self.user_id},
        {$set: {"cards.0.deck":true}}
     )
```